# exclude some specific directories from being added as categories

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm using jekyll 2.4.0 and [a plugin](https://github.com/screeninteraction/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin) for multilingual support static site generation. my problem is that the mentioned plugin forces putting my `_posts` directory under two additional directories `_i18n/{lang}` and both of these are added as categories to all the posts put under.

I want to remove above directories from posts' categories, at best using a plugin but I'm not sure if thats possible at all.

I came across this [code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/e7d0b6c5a5bf50803e6475d86079ab220d629ba2/lib/jekyll/post.rb#L57) and I can see how the dir is used for generating post categories but can I override this functionality using a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I came to use following plugin for fixing that problem:

```
module Jekyll

  class Post

    alias :populate_categories_org :populate_categories
    def populate_categories
      cats = Array(categories);

      x = cats.index("that-bad-category")
      cats.delete_at(x) unless x.nil?

      self.categories = cats

      populate_categories_org
    end

  end

end
```